# Create python script to run terminal command with source

Tags: python, linux, bash, tensorflow, raspbian

Long story short, I'm trying to figure out a way to turn these command lines into a script or function in python that can be called by another python application.

These are the command lines in Linux:

```
source tflite1-env/bin/activate
python3 stream.py --modeldir=TFLite_model
```

At first I was like this will be easy its just launching the application in python - but I'm not really sure how to deal with the source part.  I thought it was just accessing the directory, but its doing something with the .csh file...

I tried a very convoluted method by creating a .sh file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
cd tflite1 
source tflite1-env/bin/activate
python3 stream.py --modeldir=TFLite_model
```

and then making a function for my main program to call said file:

```
import os
def startCamera():
os.system('sh script.sh')
```

With this method I get an error about the source not being found.

I think the issue is I'm basically trying to call too many separate processes that are terminating each other or something?  There's got to be a better way.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: instead of `sh script.sh` try `script.sh`

Comment: I tried that and it simply says script.sh not found

Comment: give absolute path of the script like `/home/user/mydir/script.sh`

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work,  thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the function to:

```
import subprocess
def startTheCamera()
  subprocess.call("/home/pi/Desktop/launchCamera.sh")
```

I used subprocess instead of os.system and included the full file path and it works now. I think maybe it only needed the full file path, even though it was all in the same directory.